# .htaccess Redirect 301 with Rewriterule not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

When I try to redirect my page, nothing happens. If anyone tries to enter `forum.example.com/forumdisplay.php?fid=1` I want them to be redirected to `forum.example.com/forum-1.php`. I am new to `.htaccess` and couldn't figure it out.

`.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /forumdisplay.php?fid=([0-9]+).php /forum-$1.php
RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.php$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` (mod_alias) and `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) belong to two different modules. You need to use mod_rewrite only for this. Try something like the following:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# Redirect direct requests for the "real" URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^forumdisplay\.php$ /forum-%1.php? [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite back to the "real" URL
RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.php$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

(`Redirect` doesn't use regex either.)

**UPDATE:** I've appended a `?` onto the end of the first `RewriteRule` *substitution* (ie. `/forum-%1.php?`). By specifying an empty query string, it removes the query string from the request. Alternatively, you can use the `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4+

Comment: Thank you. But url displays like /forum-2.php?fid=2. Is it possible to display like /forum-2.php without ?fid=2 part ?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I forgot about that... I've updated my answer.